# how can I find a date with incorrect Syntax and fix it

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I am new to python. I have a dataset I converted it to dataframe. all my dates are objects now. I need to convert them into dates in order to find the age of patients. My dimensions are 3400x14 long. there are date values inside which have incorrect syntax. I cannot find them. is there a way to find them?

```
Cdf['Birthday'] = Cdf['Birthday'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

I am using this formula to convert. I need date without time. I am getting an error which is
"DateParseError: Invalid date specified (25/15)"

Thank you for help in advance

Comment: Just search the `Birthday` column for the string `25/15`

Comment: @Barmar there could be multiple invalid values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
Cdf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(Cdf['Birthday'], errors='coerce')
```

and check for which values in this column have `NaT`s as values. All invalid dates will be converted to `NaT`. You can use

```
Cdf.loc[Cdf['date'].isnull(), 'date']
```

to find all values which are invalid.